# How to make a POST request to a Django Rest Framework API in in Volley?

Tags: android, python, django, rest, android-volley

Here is a simple http request that I make to my Django Rest Framework based API through Postman. 
[image]

I send 4 simple parameters `name`, `phone`, `password1` and `password2` in form of form-data and expect the server to return a json object containing a key named `key` whose value is a JWT (JSON web token). This is working fine Postman, but whenever I try to do the same thing in my App through volley, I get 400 bad request error. I've tried doing multiple things but all in vain.

Can someone explain to me how to simply post some data in form of form-data in volley?

Here is my code.

```
public void signUp(View View) throws Exception
   {
       queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       url = "http://<example>.com/auth/registration/";
       Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
       params.put("name","habc");
       params.put("phone","0324423");
       params.put("password1","pass");
       params.put("password2","pass");
       JsonObjectRequest add_user_request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new JSONObject(params),
               new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
               {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                       try {
                           String key = response.getString("key");
                           tv.setText(key);
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           // Handle exception 
                       }
                   }
               },
               new Response.ErrorListener()
               {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       // error.getStackTrace() doesnt print enough information
                   }
               }
       )
       {
           @Override
           public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
               Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
               params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
               return params;
           }
       };
       Toast.makeText(this,"Adding requst to queue . . ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       queue.add(add_user_request);
       queue.start();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `getParams()` method ( after the getHeaders() method ) send the data to server.

```
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name","habc");
        params.put("phone","0324423");
        params.put("password1","pass");
        params.put("password2","pass");
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the 400 Server Error. The rest API sends back a json object which contains the details about the error but I am not being able to retrieve that json object from the `VolleyError` object that I get in `Response.ErrorListner`. Can you please help me get that error.

Comment: remove the `getHeaders()` and try again .

Comment: I still receive the same error. I need to know how to print the response that the server sends even in case of an error.

Comment: In this case you have to send a StringRequest so that you can receive a plain String response .